# Canadian sales tax is wrong? / stripe-tax / stripe elements

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Elements and have Stripe Tax enabled. "Include tax in prices" is set to Automatic.

I have a pre-created customer with a valid billing address and shipping address (both the same)

When I create a subscription for that customer with stripe.subscriptions.create(...) the taxes in the returned invoice are wrong in some cases:

Any province with no provincial sales tax is OK, the invoice just has HST at the correct %

Provinces with a provincial sales tax always include the GST component correctly, whereas the provincial component is named correctly (QST /RST etc) but is **always 0%**

I'm testing from an IP address in Ontario. I don't *think* that's a problem but thought I'd mention it just in

I must be missing something, so I'd appreciate some clues!

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out now that I found the "Tax Registrations" page hidden in the overflow menu. NOT the same as the "Tax Settings" page. Obviously.